# Auditing: How to track all user activity?

Tags: linux, security

I'm looking for a way to track all user activity, regardless of how they connect (e.g. console, shell, ssh, etc.)?

I'm currently using auditd to track privileged access and .bash_history for user tracking but .bash_history is user editable...

Is there a system-level program/application/daemon to audit/track all user activity?

Comment: In what way is this related to [tag:security]? Also, you don't say what level of tracking you require. Would you, for instance, need to track (and record) what the user(s) are doing on the screen, like mouse movements? Record audio?

Comment: @Kusalananda, How is tracking user activity not related to security?  Not screen recording so much but more files accessed, programs executed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have a much better option than `auditd` as an aggregated tool but you might not have a good enough picture of what is happening. .bash_history is user-driven and as per the name is a bash feature -- the user can use another shell.

Another approach is to increase logging of most tools (pam, sshd, *dm, sudo, etc), collate them centrally and use a Security Information and Event Monitoring (SIEM) solution.

Comment: Thanks Pedro.  I was hoping for a single solution for tracking user activity for auditing purposes on Linux.  I'm currently using auditd and bash_history but am not liking bash_history since it's accessible and editable by the users themselves.  Thanks regardless.